# Swift 3 WKWebView 'URLRequest'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert? ( BUG )

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, swift3

Hello when I use WKWebView codes with Swift 3 gives me this error

> 'URLRequest'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

I think this is bug I need help or ideas ? My codes under below
Thanks

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SocialsViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {


    var webView = WKWebView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com")!
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true


    }


}
```

Comment: You need to unwrap the value by using either `!` or `?`

Comment: @JigarTarsariya I did everything with Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried with `UIWebView` only?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use URL and URLRequest instead:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://facebook.com")!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

This is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37812485/2227743: you either use NSURL and have to downcast it as URL, or you directly use the new Swift 3 structs.

If you follow the error message, your example would become:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com")!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
```

It could be even worse:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com")!
webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)
```

All this works but of course it's much better to start using URL and URLRequest in Swift 3, without using all this downcasting.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
 let myUrl = URL(string: "https://facebook.com")!
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:myUrl));
```

Comment: No. In Swift 3, it's `load`, not `loadRequest`, and I've already answered with a correct solution.

Comment: Yes! Mr Eric you already provide correct solution. I just change name to differentiate argument "url" and variable of URL struct "myUrl". which is little confusing for freshers. Thanks