# How to convert NSURLRequest to NSMutableURLRequest in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

I'm in the process of migrating one of my projects to Swift 3 and I'm hung up on converting a NSURLRequest to NSURLMutableRequest. In Swift 2 I could simply:

```
let mreq = req.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
```

But now mutableCopy is no longer a thing in Swift 3. I tried various permutations of constructors and looked in the docs for info to no avail. I must be missing something. There has to be a way to make a mutable copy of an object.

Comment: Suggestion: [don't cast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37812485/2227743), use the new Swift 3 structs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm trying to learn to "think the Swift 3 way".

Comment: Why was this question marked down?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just figured it out. Dang it was too obvious.

```
let mreq = req.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
```

becomes

```
var mreq = req
```

Comment: Just use URLRequest and declare it as var.

Comment: How do you mean? Could you provide an example? It was already a URLRequest but came from an event that passed it in as an immutable variable through 'let'. I need to make a copy of the variable and add some headers. The only way I could figure it out was to make a mutable copy was to assign it to an variable and declare it as a var.

Comment: If it came as let you can just make it variable `var req = req`

Comment: Note that I am talking about Swift 3 URLRequest not NSURLRequest.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help.