# I write some code use swift and Xcode 8,but have some error

Tags: ios

```
seesion.dataTask(with:request) { (data,res,err) in
     print("Hello")
}
```

Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)

Comment: I think I write right.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718180/ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcompletionhandler) question? Does any of them help you?

Comment: session.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest) { (data,res,err) in
            print("Hello")
        }

Comment: Don't use `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` in Swift 3 at all. Use native `URLRequest`

Comment: ok,thanks for your caution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You use this code**

```
 session.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest) { (data,res,err) in
            print("Hello")
        }
```

Comment: yeah,that's good, the code can complie successful.thank you very much