# Is swift 3 not compatible with NSURL classes on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, ios9, nsurl, swift3, ios10

I am migrating my Swift 2.2 code building and working fine on xcode 7 / ios 8 and ios 9.
As of [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067678/swift-3-ios-compatibility) Swift 3 is compatible with iOS 8 and newer. And I am also aware that I won't be able to use newer APIs.

In my app I am creating some https requests, downloading some files etc.

My assumption is that I should also be able to use the classes NSURL, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, NSMutableURLRequest, etc. all available from iOS (8.0 and later).

But either I (obiously) run into a crash running my migrated code on iOS 8.1 because I use the URL class (available from iOS 10) or the compiler complains 'NSURL' is not implicitly convertible to 'URL' (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931870/nsurl-is-not-implicitly-convertible-to-url-did-you-mean-to-use-as-to-expl)).

Therefore I am not able to use the URL class, if I want to be compatible with iOS 9.

Here is some code to make things clearer:

**Swift 2:**

```
class ServerCom: NSObject, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {
   private var fileURL: NSURL = NSURL()
    [...]       
           guard let urlString: NSURL =
        NSURL(string: params,
            relativeToURL: NSURL(string: dcParam.baseURL) )  else {
                let failed = "Could not generate URL from: \(dcParam.baseURL)\(params)"
                throw fetchAppXmlError.FAILED_URL_GENERATION(failed)
    }
    [...]
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: urlString)
    request.timeoutInterval = 10
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

}
```

**Swift 3**

```
class ServerCom: NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

 fileprivate var localFileURL: NSURL = NSURL()

 [...]

         guard let urlString: NSURL =
            NSURL(string: params,
                relativeTo: NSURL(string: dcParam.baseURL) )  else {
                    let failed = "Could not generate URL from: \(dcParam.baseURL)\(params)"
                    throw fetchAppXmlError.failed_URL_GENERATION(failed)
        }

 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlString)
 request.timeoutInterval = 10
 request.httpMethod = "GET"
 [...]

}
```

In the swift 3 code I get the following errors:

1. At the line with: let request = ...:  'NSURL' is not implicitly convertible to 'URL'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
2. At the line with let urlString = ...: Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL?' to expected argument type 'URL?'

I can't use localFileURL with type URL because this would be iOS 10 only.
I also can't use URLRequest instead of NSMutableURLRequest because it is also only available from iOS (10.0 and later). It seems that I always use somehow URLs of type URL rather than the "old" NSURL.

So my question is: Is there *any* way to use NSURL et. al. with swift 3 **and** iOS 9?

Or in more general, is there a way to do background downloads with swift 3 that will work on iOS 9 and iOS 10?

Does this inconsistency come from the bridging of NSURLComponents to URLComponents?

Comment: You can easily bride the Foundation and Swift types e.g. `urlString as URL` without exclamation/question mark after `as`

Comment: This is wrong: _I can't use localFileURL with type URL because this would be iOS 10 only._ Apps using `URL` or `URLRequest` run on iOS 9 devices without problem. The `Availability` notes are sort of confusing, but if you properly set Deployment Target, Xcode/Swift will warn you actually unavailable things. Try using `URL` and `URLRequest` and test it on actual iOS 9 device.

Comment: Thanks OOPer! Your hint took me to the right direction! These availability notes are really confusing. I now can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [OOPer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6541007/ooper) i can answer my own question:

the code works fine with the URL class but only when you set the Deplyoment Target to the **same** iOS Version as your simulator!

XCode 8 updated my iOS 9 SDK to version 10 and so I only had the choice to use the simulator on either iOS 10 or iOS 8.1. However the Deployment Target was set to iOS 9 (I was pretty sure that it was before the upgrade set to iOS 8.1).

So I run into the runtime error with an iOS 8.1 simulator and Deployment Target set to iOS 9.

But it does **work** with iOS 8.1 simulator **and** Deployment Target set to iOS 8.1!

Here is the Swift 3 Code working also with iOS 8.1:

```
class ServerCom: NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

fileprivate var localFileURL: URL = URL(string: "dummy")!

 [...]

         guard let urlString: URL =
            URL(string: params,
                relativeTo: URL(string: dcParam.baseURL) )  else {
                    let failed = "Could not generate URL from: \(dcParam.baseURL)\(params)"
                    throw fetchAppXmlError.failed_URL_GENERATION(failed)
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: urlString)
        request.timeoutInterval = 10
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
 [...]

}
```

Thank you!