# Swift/Xcode error trying to set up UIWebView: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I'm very new to development in Swift and Xcode and would love some pointers. I just started looking at it today and thought I'd start out with creating an app for iPhone that simply acts as a webwrapper. Though, I've only dragged in a `UIwebView` and written 4 lines of code that I found here on stackoverflow, it's already all going to hell.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it's something simple.

I've only got experience with simple front-end for web as well as PHP and some Java so Swift looks somewhat weird to me.

> The error I'm getting is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mjuk.se/frånvaro")!
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfxTW.png)

Comment: `NSURL(string: "http://www.mjuk.se/frånvaro")!` is not valid because of the `å` character, so it returns nil, and since you're *force unwrapping* the result, it crashes the app, *as expected*. You have to percent encode your URL.

Comment: You should also use `URL` and `URLRequest` [without making conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet), and learn to work with Optionals, it's explained in the Swift manual.

Comment: As mentioned by @EricAya , the reason you might have NSURL is nil. Use UTF8 encoding for URL string.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This fixed the error but now the webview is empty in the simulator. The webpage isn't loading at all it seems. I also tried with different websites, such as google.com. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the issue. Thanks for all the help guys, I will keep all of this in mind!