# Xcode Swift 3 NSURLSession.sharedSession

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8, nsurlsession, nsurl

Im trying to update my basic weather app i made with swift 2 to swift 3 this is my code:

```
func getWeather(city: String) {

    let path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=095711373620570aa92ee530246dc8af"
    let url = NSURL(string: path)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print(">>>> \(data)")
    }
```

and NSURLSession.sharedSession(5th line) and NSURLResponse(6th line) print out an error

Comment: Try re-writing the line. Xcode helps you with the new syntax when autocompleting / suggesting members.

Comment: Have tried it doesnt work...

Comment: Hint: `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` -> `URLSession.shared`

Comment: Thanks that works but NSURLResponse is still giving a error

Comment: Drop the NS prefix. use Data, URLResponse, Error instead.

Comment: Swift 2 to Swift 3: https://swift.org/migration-guide/

Comment: now Url! gives a error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 URLSession.shared() Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:) error (bug)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't annotate types in the completion handler signature and use the Swift 3 native structures:

```
func getWeather(city: String) {

    let path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=095711373620570aa92ee530246dc8af"
    let url = URL(string: path)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(">>>> \(data)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 update

URLSession.shared.dataTask()

Comment: Any chance you could explain your answer a bit more in detail? Please see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)