# ambiguous use of selector dataTask(with: completionHandler:)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, selector, nsurlsession

I'm trying to get a `selector` of the [`dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask) method defined in `URLSession` which uses `URLRequest` object like below, but getting error as there are two methods with slightly two different params names (overloaded methods - 1. one uses URLRequest object as param and another uses URL) :

```
let dataTaskSelector = #selector(URLSession.dataTask(with: completionHandler:))
```

I have tried a different approach like below (mentioned in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md ) but it's also giving same error :

```
let mySelector = #selector((URLSession.dataTask(with: completionHandler:)) as (URLSession) -> (URLRequest, (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDataTask)
```

[image]

I'm using latest Xcode and swift 3. I didn't find good documentation with similar example on this unfortunately so far. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @vadian, Sorry to inform you that the question is different here and I didn't find any answer about how to create a selector for this method without this error.

Comment: @Sri, The question is different here. you were too quick to point out that link. I have already gone through that before posting this.

Comment: I reopened the question. Why don't you create a custom selector/method which calls the appropriate method of `URLSession`?

Comment: @vadian, hmm...that would be a way to bypass the original problem. I need the correct Swift technique to create selectors.

Comment: Standard selector is `#selector(methodName)` or with a parameter `#selector(methodName(_:))`

Comment: @NiravD As you can see I've already reopened the question.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for reopening it.

Comment: @vadian, you are right.. I have tried the standard selector syntax already but this is a case of Swift's new method naming convention and I'm not able to find correct way to make the selector without this error.

Comment: Might be help with This :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet/40542471#40542471

Comment: @Saumil, unfortunately the problem is different here than what your link has solution for. But thanks a lot for replying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 URLSession.shared() Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:) error (bug)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write that `selector` like this way.

```
let selector = #selector((URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)) as (URLSession) -> (URLRequest, @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask)
```

This `#selector` [tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hannibal-selector/) help me to get the solution.

Comment: Great !!! Thanks a ton Nirav :)
I was trying with the syntax very close to you but missed the word "@escaping". 
Also can you change the syntax to use URLRequest instead of URL to match with the exact question. Doesn't matter for me though.. I got what I needed .. thanks again :)

Comment: @Tushar Welcome mate and edited answer for `URLRequest`:)

Comment: So people don't miss it, You need to cast it as ```as ((MyClass) -> (MyMethodType))?``` not just ```as (MyMethodType)```

Comment: @Tylerc230 Yes, But here (MyMethodType) is methods parameter list separated by `,`.

Comment: Error in Xcode 11.5:
`Cannot convert value of type '(URLSession) -> (URL, @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask' to type '(URLSession) -> (URLRequest, @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask' in coercion`