# Why does it need to force unwrap the selector to avoid swift ambiguous reference error

Tags: ios, swift3, selector, xcode8.2

I'm following Swift's already implemented proposal guide https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md to make an unambiguous selector declaration.

But the following code gives error:

> amibiguous reference to member urlSession(_:dataTask:didBecome)"

[image]

```
let sel = #selector((URLSessionDataDelegate.urlSession(_:dataTask:didBecome:)) as (URLSessionDataDelegate) -> (URLSession, URLSessionDataTask, URLSessionDownloadTask) -> Void)
```

But after adding force unwrap, the error goes away:

```
let sel = #selector((URLSessionDataDelegate.urlSession(_:dataTask:didBecome:))! as (URLSessionDataDelegate) -> (URLSession, URLSessionDataTask, URLSessionDownloadTask) -> Void)
```

My question is -  What is the correct way to make the selector here? Why does the error go away by adding force-unwrap? And am I doing it right by adding force unwrap here?

Comment: Compare with this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/41546717/6433023

Comment: Thanks for the link @Nirav. But that solution doesn't apply here because the problem is a bit different.