# Getting Json from url using session

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am using xcode 9 beta 5 .I trying to parse the url .While maintaining session based on url the code is giving syntax error .

```
 static func fetchFeatureApp(){
        let urlString="http://ebmacs.net/ubereats/Api/all_product?id=1"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURLRequest(url: urlString)) { (data, responce, error) in
            if error!=nil
            {
                print(error)
                return

            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjOU3.jpg)

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURLRequest(url: urlString)) { (data, responce, error) in
```

This line of code is giving error

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'
>   How to correct this

How I can remove this error ?
I have visited this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet)

Answer (score 0):

`URLRequest` expects an `URL` rather than a `String`, that's what the error message states.

```
let urlString = "http://ebmacs.net/ubereats/Api/all_product?id=1"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url)) { (data, responce, error) in ...
```

You *visited link* clearly creates the `URL` from the string.

But actually you don't need an `URLRequest` for  a simple GET request, just pass the `URL`

```
let url = URL(string: "http://ebmacs.net/ubereats/Api/all_product?id=1")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, responce, error) in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is my favourite code for `urlsession` download,

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "Your URL String")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
     let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) //if you want to convert to Json  
 }.resume()
```